# Parse this date in Python: 5th November 2010

Tags: python, date-formatting, python-datetime

I'm having a bad time with date parsing and formatting today.

Points for somebody who can parse this date format into a `datetime.date` or `datetime.datetime` (I'm not too fussy but I'd prefer `.date`):

`5th November 2010`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil):

```
In [2]: import dateutil.parser as dparser

In [3]: date = dparser.parse('5th November 2010')

In [4]: date
Out[4]: datetime.datetime(2010, 11, 5, 0, 0)
```

Comment: `dateutil` is definitely the cleanest.

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately, `strptime` has no format characters for "skip an ordinal suffix" -- so, I'd do the skipping first, with a little RE, and then parse the resulting "clear" string.  I.e.:

```
>>> import re
>>> import datetime
>>> ordn = re.compile(r'(?<=\d)(st|nd|rd|th)\b')
>>> def parse(s):
...   cleans = ordn.sub('', s)
...   dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(cleans, '%d %B %Y')
...   return dt.date()
... 
>>> parse('5th November 2010')
datetime.date(2010, 11, 5)
```

Your preference for `date` vs `datetime` is no problem of course, that's what the `.date()` method of `datetime` objects is for;-).

Third-party extensions like [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) can be useful if you need to do a lot of "fuzzy" date parsing (or other fancy date-related stuff;-), by the way.

Comment: +1 for not including a 3rd party module. Although the dateutil package looks awesome, sometimes it can be a pain to get 3rd party modules installed (especially when the developer doesn't have 100% control over the environment)

Answer (score 5):

If the ordinal is constant then:

```
datetime.strptime(s, '%dth %B %Y')
```

Else:

```
date_str = '5th November 2010'
modified_date_str = date_str[0:1] + date_str[3:]
datetime.strptime(modified_date_str, '%d %B %Y')
```

Or like [~unutbu said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461435/parse-this-date-in-python-5th-november-2010/3461462#3461462) use dateutil :)

Comment: Your second solution wouldn't work too well if `date_str` was, say, `25th November 2010` -- that's why in my A I'm using a RE, rather than plain string slicing, to strip the ordinal suffix;-).

Comment: @Alex: You are correct. Some kind of matching/cleanup *is* required.