# Extract date ("05/Jan/2014") from string

Tags: python, string, parsing, date, datetime

I would like to extract date from a string like :

```
15/Nov/2013
05/Jan/2014
```

and reformat it like this

```
15/11/2013
05/01/2014
```

**Is there a ready-to-use function for this (that already "knows" months : Jan, Feb, etc.) ?**

Comment: [Yes, there is such a function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your locale is english, then the standard `datetime` module will parse month abbreviations for you:

```
import datetime

date = datetime.datetime.strptime(inputvalue, '%d/%b/%Y').date()
```

C (English month names) is the default locale, so this should work anywhere you don't set the Python locale explicitly. As long as you don't call [`locale.setlocale()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html#locale.setlocale) or [`locale.resetlocale()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html#locale.resetlocale) anywhere you can count on the above to work correctly.

Formatting these back to a different format is then trivial:

```
date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

Demo:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('15/Nov/2013', '%d/%b/%Y').date()
datetime.date(2013, 11, 15)
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('05/Jan/2014', '%d/%b/%Y').date()
datetime.date(2014, 1, 5)
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('15/Nov/2013', '%d/%b/%Y').date().strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
'15/11/2013'
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('05/Jan/2014', '%d/%b/%Y').date().strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
'05/01/2014'
```

Comment: Is there any method to convert "25th November, 2016" this type to string to date object?

Comment: @Soumen: [Parse this date in Python: 5th November 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3461435)

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('15/Nov/2013', '%d/%b/%Y').strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
'15/11/2013'
```

As Martijn Pieters noted, your locale should be English (e.g. `en_US`) for this to work. If you haven't done anything to alter locale, it will presumably be some flavor of English.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to go with [dateutil.parser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil) to convert a string to a python datetime object. It has so far managed to handle every conversion I have wanted to do. Once you have it in a datetime object, you can easily convert it to a string format of your choice.

```
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> dateutil.parser.parse('15/Nov/2013').strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
'15/11/2013'
```

The function would, at the same time be able to handle other formats, e.g. `YYYY-mm-DD` without any changes from your side.

```
>>> dateutil.parser.parse('2013-11-15').strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
'15/11/2013'
```